# How do i add an attr using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do i add an attr using javascript:

Here is the code:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active">
    <a href="#tab_1_4" data-toggle="tab" id="8" onclick="TableIdByNew(this.id)"><span class="badge badge-default" id="sipp-count">0</span> New </a>

  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#tab_1_2" data-toggle="tab" id="9" onclick="TableIdByInProgress(this.id)"><span class="badge badge-default" id="sass-count">0</span> InProgress </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#tab_1_3" data-toggle="tab" id="10" onclick="TableIdByClosed(this.id)"><span class="badge badge-default" id="sass-counts">0</span> Closed </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I want to add the :

```
  $("8").attr("aria-expanded", "true");
  $("9").attr("aria-expanded", "false");
  $("10").attr("aria-expanded", "false");
```

but this is not working.

here is the table:

```
<div class="tab-pane active in" id="tab_1_4" style="display:none">
                        <p>
                            <div class="portlet box">
                                <div class="portlet-title">


                                    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive table-hover" width="100%" id="AdminTicketId4" cellspacing="0">
                                        <thead>


                                            <tr>
                                                <th> Date Created </th>
                                                <th> Title </th>
                                                <th> User Name </th>
                                                <th> User Email </th>
                                                <th> Assigned To </th>
                                                <th>Importancy</th>
                                                <th> Status </th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>

                                    </table>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </p>
                    </div>
```

the table is here:

this is the first table okay.

how do i solve??

where is the wrong???

Comment: `$("#8")` i suggest dont make number first character. Missing `#`

Comment: @guradio is right. To select html elements with jquery by id, you need the hashtag `#`

Comment: not working....

Comment: Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #[object HTMLTableElement]

Comment: _Not working_...is not giving any details that what bad happend to your computer. What didn't work? Do you get any error?

Comment: Before you can use `.attr()` or other jQuery methods you have to start with jQuery basics of how to select elements with `$()`.

Comment: @manoj The error says well, that is a table element not the one you posted in your question.

Comment: jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #[object HTMLTableElement]
    at Function.fa.error (jquery.min.js:2)
    at fa.tokenize (jquery.min.js:2)
    at fa.select (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Function.fa [as find] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at n.fn.init.find (jquery.min.js:2)
    at n.fn.init (jquery.min.js:2)
    at n (jquery.min.js:2)
    at TableIdBy (adminticketlist.js:957)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (AdminTicket:223)

Comment: That error looks like something you'd get if you concatenated `"#"` with a variable that you thought was a string but was actually a DOM element. Given that none of the code shown does anything like that we can't help you further unless you [edit] your question to show the relevant part of your real code.

Comment: i am not getting..why this error ??elaborate.. and tell me some way to find the solutions

Comment: Are you saying that the *only* JS code you are running is exactly as shown in the answers below, and running *that* code produces the error you're quoting in the comments? The edit to your question doesn't make much sense, because you've shown more HTML but not whatever JS is producing the error you're asking about in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery selectors work like CSS selectors.

To select an element by its ID (`this_is_an_id`), use `$('#this_is_an_id')`. Mind the `#` - without it, you would be matching an element of the type `this_is_an_id`. Think of `$('li')` as an example that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("#8").attr("aria-expanded", "true");
        $("#9").attr("aria-expanded", "false");
        $("#10").attr("aria-expanded", "false");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="#tab_1_4" data-toggle="tab" id="8" onclick="TableIdByNew(this.id)"><span class="badge badge-default" id="sipp-count">0</span> New </a>

                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#tab_1_2" data-toggle="tab" id="9" onclick="TableIdByInProgress(this.id)"><span class="badge badge-default" id="sass-count">0</span> InProgress </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#tab_1_3" data-toggle="tab" id="10" onclick="TableIdByClosed(this.id)"><span class="badge badge-default" id="sass-counts">0</span> Closed </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

Comment: Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #[object HTMLTableElement]

Comment: @manoj - That error can't be reproduced with the code shown in the question. Notice that the code in this answer can be run directly via the "Run code snippet" button, and it works as is... (A little bit of explanation in the answer would have been nice, but still, the code works.)

Comment: In your question you only mention how to add attr...In my answer this attr is added.

Answer (score 1):

You have specified **id="8"** and so on, so you have to use **"#"** to use with JQuery, try as below:

```
$("#8").attr("aria-expanded", "true");
```

Answer (score 1):

You asked how to add them in Javascript, not in jQuery. This is how it is done in Javascript ([demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QvNBde)):

```
<ul>
  <li><a id="8">New</a></li>
  <li><a id="9">InProgress</a></li>
  <li><a id="10">Closed</a></li>
</ul>

<script>
document.getElementById('8').setAttribute('aria-expanded', 'true');
document.getElementById('9').setAttribute('aria-expanded', 'false');
document.getElementById('10').setAttribute('aria-expanded', 'false');
</script>
```

You probably meant jQuery, but please note that you [you might not need jquery.com](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/). Javascript has come a long way.

Comment: *"You asked how to add them in Javascript, not in jQuery"* - If I use jQuery then I have used JavaScript, though of course you are right that for something simple like this jQuery doesn't really make it much easier. But clearly the OP just meant "add them programmatically", and *is* using jQuery in a general sense.

Comment: Sure, I know that (see my answer). But I am not answering for the OP. I am answering this question for Google/The InterWebz: 'How do i add an attr using javascript?'.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("a[id=8]").attr("aria-expanded", "true");
$("a[id=9]").attr("aria-expanded", "false");
$("a[id=10]").attr("aria-expanded", "false");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active">
    <a href="#tab_1_4" data-toggle="tab" id="8" onclick="TableIdByNew(this.id)"><span class="badge badge-default" id="sipp-count">0</span> New </a>

  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#tab_1_2" data-toggle="tab" id="9" onclick="TableIdByInProgress(this.id)"><span class="badge badge-default" id="sass-count">0</span> InProgress </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#tab_1_3" data-toggle="tab" id="10" onclick="TableIdByClosed(this.id)"><span class="badge badge-default" id="sass-counts">0</span> Closed </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Use [attribute selecotr](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) like `[id=8]` where `id=8`

> Description: Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value exactly equal to a certain value.

Or you can change your id to not start with number and just use `#` to select the `ID`

Comment: Why wouldn't you use `"#8"`?

Comment: Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #[object HTMLTableElement]
    at Function.fa.error (jquery.min.js:2)
    at fa.tokenize (jquery.min.js:2)
    at fa.select (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Function.fa [as find] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at n.fn.init.find (jquery.min.js:2)
    at n.fn.init (jquery.min.js:2)
    at n (jquery.min.js:2)
    at TableIdBy (adminticketlist.js:956)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (AdminTicket:226)

Comment: @manoj The error says well, that is a table element not the one you posted in your question.

Comment: @nnnnnn it should work like what i commented above this is just an alternate solution since alot of people answered it already